# Bash: Ensure a command always runs when using set -euo pipefail

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script in Bash that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Stop the script if any commands fail
set -euo pipefail

# Start a server
yarn serve &
SERVER_PID=$!

# Run some cURL requests against the server
...

# Stop the server
kill $SERVER_PID
```

What I'd like to do is ensure `kill $SERVER_PID` is always called at the end of the script, even if one of the server commands fails. Is there a way to accomplish this in Bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert

```
trap "kill $SERVER_PID" ERR
```

in a new line after `SERVER_PID=$!`.

From `help trap`:

> ERR means to execute ARG each time a command's failure would cause the
>       shell to exit when the -e option is enabled.

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Stop the script if any commands fail
set -euo pipefail

# Start a server
yarn serve &
SERVER_PID=$!

trap "kill $SERVER_PID" 0 1 2 3 15

# Run some cURL requests against the server
...
```

Note the use of `trap`